# Integration in closed form

Tags: integration

Is there any trig substitution or any other way to solve the following integrand in closed form ($u>0$)
$$
\int_{\frac{2u}{3}}^{2u} \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2\pi \sqrt{u-\frac{1}{2}x}\times \sqrt{-u+\frac{3}{2}x}}dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

By changes of variable $y=ux$ then $t=y-2/3$

I get $$I=\frac 1{\pi}e^{-\frac u3}\int_0^{\frac 43} \frac{e^{-\frac 12 ut}}{\sqrt{t(4-3t)}}$$

And now the CAS is happy to give a solution $I=\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}e^{-\frac {2u}3}\operatorname{BesselI}(0, \frac u3)$